# part of material not showing up in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm pretty new to blender.

I want to make a silver ring with the "925" stamp inside. I realized the stamp via a bump map (black and white image from Photoshop). That map drives the darker color as well.

It looks nice enough in the viewport (Cycles), but in the final render the stamp is somehow there but not really.
[image]

The ring has a diameter of approx 20 mm. I have a feeling that the stamp is somehow too small for the path tracing engine. Does that even make sense?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any modifiers applied to ring, maybe something that has different settings for the viewport compared to the render?

Comment: You're on the right track. It's the bevel modifier. Let me fiddle with it - I'll post the solution when I have it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:
I have a bevel modifier on the ring itself. I did apply it to a vertex group (the edges of the ring). I now changed it to "limit method: weight" after I gave those edges a mean weight of 1. Now it works fine.
The reason I didn't see the problem before in the viewport was that I accidentally had the modifier hidden in the viewport.
Shoutout to @Robert_Gützow for the right idea.